# Error after Installing Octave in Ubuntu do my error have any solution

Tags: gui, octave

I installed octave by using the:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

command but after I am unable to open octave I tried by typing `octave` and also tried:

```
octave --force-gui
```

[image: picture]

Output of `ls -ld ~/ .config/octave`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 20 23:38 .config/octave
drwxr-xr-x 15 chaitu chaitu 4096 Jan 21 06:27 /home/chaitu/
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld ~/.config/octave`? Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: This is the second or third time I've seen something like this - I wonder if there's a bug in the octave installation process?

Comment: After purging and reinstalling octave on my 16.10 system I can confirm that installation creates a root-owned ~/.config/octave dir and qt-settings file

Comment: In reply to David Forester  for output(ls -ld ~/ .config/octave)                  drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jan 20 23:38 .config/octave
drwxr-xr-x 15 chaitu chaitu 4096 Jan 21 06:27 /home/chaitu/

Comment: The error is all about root user . This error occurs when we try to install the octave in ubuntu if we are not in root user mode. By default the ubuntu root user is locked.

Answer (score 1):

[According to steeldriver](/questions/874251/error-after-installing-octave-in-ubuntu-do-my-error-have-any-solution#comment1357595_874251) this is what happens during the installation of Octave. I consider that a bug and it would help if you [report it on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave).

As a work-around you can reset the ownership on that directory:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER:" ~/.config/octave
```