# Octave not running on Ubuntu 16.04. Give the following error/message

Tags: 16.04, permissions, octave

After `sudo apt-get update` and the `sudo apt-get install octave` when i type octave in the terminal I get the following message:

*The settings file /home/ameya/.config/octave/qt-settings does not exist and can not be created. Make sure you have read and write permissions to /home/ameya/.config/octave
Octave GUI must be closed now.*

How do I give permission or make the folder that needs to be created? I'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with the installation process - see for example [Error after Installing Octave in Ubuntu do my error have any solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/874251/error-after-installing-octave-in-ubuntu-do-my-error-have-any-solution). Try `sudo chown -R $USER:USER ~/.config/octave`

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to create  `/home/ameya/.config/octave` you need to do the
   following:

```
mkdir -p /home/ameya/.config/octave
```

[mkdir man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir)

> ```
> -p, --parents <br>
>     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
> ```

2. In order to give read/write permission on  `/home/ameya/.config/octave` you need to do the following:

```
chmod 755 -R /home/ameya/.config/octave
```

[chmod man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

> ```
> -R, --recursive
>     change files and directories recursively
> ```

Comment: **Thanks for your help** *chmod: changing permissions of '/home/ameya/.config/octave': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/ameya/.config/octave/qt-settings': Operation not permitted.* This is what i get when i type *chmod 755 -R /home/ameya/.config/octave*

Comment: Did you try  `sudo chown -R $USER:USER ~/.config/octave` as suggested by steeldriver ?